# Kali Linux Wi-Fi is not showing

Tags: linux, kali-linux, pci, wifi-driver

Today I tried connecting a Wi-Fi dongle so I could get more range on my laptop, and everything worked fine.

After I got home, I disconnected the dongle (while the computer was on) and then the PCI Wi-Fi card didn’t connect! 
It showed the Wi-Fi icon but with no text and without any visible networks:
[image: No Networks]
[image: Empty Icon]

I tried to fix it but with no success.
The USB dongle still works on the laptop.

I also tried my full-kali-install-on-usb, and it did work with the PCI card.

System info:

```
root@nadav-asus:~# lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NE785 / AW-NE785H 802.11bgn Wireless Full or Half-size Mini PCIe Card [1a3b:1089]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
root@nadav-asus:~# uname -a
Linux nadav-asus 4.13.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.13.4-2kali1 (2017-10-16) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@nadav-asus:~# rfkill list
0: asus-wimax: WiMAX
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
root@nadav-asus:~#
```

Comment: yup, in ten minutes

Comment: edited the post

Comment: still not working...

Comment: I'm considering reinstalling kali, although i dont want to... is there any way to just do the network part of the installation?

Comment: dhclient wlan0 is just stuck (yes wlan0 is my interface)

Comment: connect through rj45 , remove the `network-manager` package then install wicd :  `apt remove network-manager` then `apt install wicd` and reboot

Comment: well i installed wicd and rebooted and nothing happened...

Comment: What is the output of `lsmod | grep ath9k` ?

Comment: nadav@nadav-asus:~$ sudo lsmod | grep ath9k
[sudo] password for nadav: 
ath9k                  94208  0
ath9k_common           16384  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              442368  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_hw,ath9k,ath9k_common
mac80211              659456  1 ath9k
cfg80211              598016  4 mac80211,ath9k,ath,ath9k_common
nadav@nadav-asus:~$

Comment: no output from that